# Initializing inner struct in emplace_back()

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have struct which contains array of inner struct. I want to use method `emplace_back()` of `vector<my_struct>`. But I cannot figure how could I initialize this struct correctly:

```
struct my_struct
{
    struct
    {
        float x, y, z;
    } point[3];
};

std::vector<my_struct> v;

v.emplace_back(
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0},
    {0, 0, 0}
);
```

This gives compilation error `error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<main()::my_struct>::emplace_back(<brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>, <brace-enclosed initializer list>)`

Is it possible to emplace_back this struct (I'm using C++17)? Should I write custom constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about this:

```
v.push_back(my_struct{{{0, 1, 2}, {3, 4, 5}, {6, 7, 8}}});
```

Comment: Yes, `v.push_back()` is working, but it is possible with `emplace_back()`?

Comment: @AndrejKesely It is the same thing: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14b2087f25634e90

Comment: @Amadeus I see, push_back() is working even like this `v.push_back({{{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0}}});`, in emplace_back() I need to specify `my_struct` first: `v.emplace_back(my_struct{{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0}}});` Why?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Maybe this explain for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43395138/2293156