# Is it possible to emplace a std::array in a container? If it is how? If not, why?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdarray, emplace

Given the simple code

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int,3>> v;
    v.emplace_back(std::array<int,3>{1,2,3});
}
```

I'm first of all worried about what is really going on.

My understanding of `emplace_back` is that it constructs an element (in this case an `std::array<int,3>` with values `1`, `2`, `3`) in-place by forwarding its argument(s) to that element's constructor.

But which constructor? Since we are passing an object of the same type of the element we want to emplace, I guess the move constructor is selected, as we're passing a temporary, or the copy ctor if the move ctor is deleted (implicitly or explicitly). Besides, we are first of all constructing that temporary, and that's *not* done in place, right?

So we are basically calling the "normal" (???) constructor of `std::array<int,3>` by passing to it `1`, `2` , and `3` as arguments, thus getting back a temporary, which is passed to the copy ctor of `std::array<int,3>` which constructs the copy in place or, preferably, to the move ctor of `std::array<int,3>` which (?) copies the underlying C-style pointer?

It should be clear this simple example is confusing me a lot.

To confuse me even more is the doubt that if I really wanted to take advantage of `emplace_back`, I could pass to it only the arguments to the `std::array<int,3>`, as in

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::array<int,3>> v;
    v.emplace_back(1,2,3);
}
```

[which doesn't even compile.](https://godbolt.org/z/x3orG4)

Comment: `std::array` has no user-defined constructors. It uses Aggregate Initialization.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43394841/103167 (both the "struct" in the other question and your `std::array` are aggregates requiring aggregate initialization).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let me try to clarify a bit. First of, `std::array<>` is an [aggregate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It does not have any user-defined constructors at all.

So it is quasi-movable (technical term is [trivially movable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor)), meaning you can construct it from temporary, but it is going to simply copy the underlying array. So what the code ends up doing is copying supplied array into the newly allocated vector element.

You would achieve identical results (but will do slightly less typing) if you replace the `emplace_back` with `push_back` like following:

```
    v.push_back({1,2,3});
```

And `emplace_back(1, 2, 3)` doesn't compile because `std::array<>` does not have any constructors which take more than one argument.

Comment: Why is a whole copy needed when using a temporary `std::array` to construct a `std::array`? Couldn't the pointer be stolen from the temporary to the object being created?

Comment: @Enrico `std::array` does not have a stoleable pointer, because it does not manage a dynamically allocated memory. This is the main difference between `std::array<>` and `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Oh, sure! It's just that `std::vector<T>` has a `T * ptr;` in it, `ptr` being a modifiable lvalue, whereas `std::array<T,N>` has a `T arr[N];` in it, which is a non-modifiable lvalue.

Comment: In C++20 ```emplace_back``` can initialize aggregates, but still cannot initialize std::array, so they are fundamentally differ.

Comment: @Fedor can you please clarify your comment?

Comment: In C++20 one can use ```emplace_back``` for aggregates without any user ctor, but still not for ```std::array```. So we cannot say that aggregates and ```std::array``` behave similar in C++20 any more.

Comment: @Fedor, I think, you are confused. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array - "This container is an aggregate type with the same semantics as a struct holding a C-style array..."

Comment: I just say that ```emplace_back``` shall work for aggregates in C++20: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68006844/why-does-clang-12-refuse-to-initialize-aggregates-in-the-c20-way