# Is it possible to swap std::array in constant time?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, std

From what I understand, swapping a `std::vector` is a constant time operation because the only pointers are being swapped, but in the case of an `std::array` the swapping is element-wise. Is it possible to swap the pointers of an `std::array`?

Apologies if this has been asked to death already. If so kindly point me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: `std::array` doesn't have any pointers in the first place. It's just a wrapper around a C-style array

Comment: You  can certainly use two `std::array` pointers pointing to two array instances, and swap those pointers. That may or may not be good enough for the algorithm you are trying to implement.

Comment: If an array holds elements that are pointers or other trivial types, they can be copied to another array in constant time, using memcpy(), an optimized std::copy(), etc. But non-trivial types can't be. If you want to swap the elements of 2 arrays, then they have to be swapped individually.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That wouldn't be constant time in terms of the number of entries in the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `std::vector` as something ***along these lines***

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct vector {
    T * pointer;
    int N; // well, not really int
    // the several constructors allocate memory, set N, and do other stuff if necessary
    // Other stuff
};
```

so there's the pointer you refer to, the one which is swapped when you swap two vectors.

But `std::array` is more like this

```cpp
template<typename T, int N> // again, not really int
struct array {
    T elements[N];
    // other stuff
};
```

so there's no pointer here, just statically allocated memory.

(Learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64921466/is-it-possible-to-emplace-a-stdarray-in-a-container-if-it-is-how-if-not-why/64921517#comment114779919_64921517).)

Answer (score 2):

There are no "pointers of a `std::array`". The `array` *is its contents*; it doesn't point to anything any more than a class with an `int` member "points" to that member.