# Why does Clang 12 refuse to initialize aggregates in the C++20 way?

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, emplace, aggregate-initialization

As far as I understand, the following program should work in C++20 mode:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct B{ int a0, a1; };

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> bs;
    bs.emplace_back( 0, 0 );
}
```

And it really does in Visual Studio 2019 and gcc 11. But not in clang 12, which produces the error:

```
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-snapshot/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/12.0.0/../../../../include/c++/12.0.0/bits/alloc_traits.h:514:4: error: no matching function for call to 'construct_at'
          std::construct_at(__p, std::forward<_Args>(__args)...);
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

In online compiler: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/GzccTWc5z

Is this because clang does not fully support C++20 yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a C++20 feature that allows aggregate initialization through the standard constructor syntax, rather than the typical braced-list initialization syntax. (Note that this only works if the parameters cannot be used in a valid call to a default or copy/move constructor. If they could, that would be called instead of performing aggregate initialization.)

According to the official [C++ Support in Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) page, Clang does not yet support parenthesized initialization of aggregates (which is [P0960R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0960r3.html) and [P1975R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1975r0.html)). This is as of Clang version 13.

A support matrix for C++20 features is also maintained [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support/20). This shows that support for P0960R3 is as follows:

- GCC: supported as of version 10
- MSVC: supported as of version 19.28
- EDG eccp: supported as of version 5.1
- Clang and Apple Clang: unsupported
- Intel ICC: unsupported

Comment: "Note that this only works if the parameters cannot be used in a valid call to a default or copy/move constructor. If they could, that would be called instead of performing aggregate initialization.". At least that is consistent with brace-init which behaves in the same way AFAIK. Or is there a difference here? One thing comes to mind: I suspect if the initializer has an implicit conversion to the aggregate type, things could behave different.

Comment: Note that Clang 16 now supports it, but it's still unavailable on Apple clang.