# How to control the size of a class to be a multiple of the size of a member?

Tags: c++, struct, alignment, padding, sizeof

I have the following class,

```
struct employee {
    std::string name;
    short salary;
    std::size_t age;
};
```

Just as an example, in Linux amd64, the size of the struct is 48 bytes, and the size of std::string is 32, that is, not a multiple.

Now, I need, in a cross-platform way, for `employee` to have a size that is a multiple of the size of `std::string` (first member).

(Cross-platform could mean, for example, both Linux amd64 and Apple ARM.)

That is, `sizeof(employee) % sizeof(std::string) == 0`.

I tried controlling the padding using `alignas` for the whole class or the members, but the requirement to be a power of 2 is too restrictive, it seems.

Then I tried to add a `char` array at the end.
Still, I had two problems, first, what is the exact size of the array in different platforms at compile-time, and second not adding another member that can screw up the nice aggregate initialization of the class.

For the first, I do this:

```
struct employee_dummy {
    std::string name;
    short salary;
    std::size_t age;
};

struct employee {
    std::string name;
    short salary;
    std::size_t age;
    char padding[(sizeof(employee_dummy)/sizeof(std::string)+1)*sizeof(std::string) - sizeof(employee_dummy)];
};
```

Note the ugly dummy class, and I don't even know if the logic is correct.

For the second problem, I don't have a solution.
I could do this, but then I would need to add a constructor, the class would not be an aggregate, etc.

```
struct employee {
    std::string name;
    short salary;
    std::size_t age;
 private:
    char padding[(sizeof(employee_dummy)/sizeof(std::string)+1)*sizeof(std::string) - sizeof(employee_dummy)];
};
```

**How can I control the size of the struct with standard or non-standard mechanisms and keep the class as an aggregate?**

Here is a link to play with this problem empirically: https://cppinsights.io/s/f2fb5239

---

NOTE ADDED:

I realized that, if the technique to add padding is correct, the calculation is even more difficult because the dummy class might be already adding padding, so I have to take into account the offset of the last element instead.

In this example I want `data` to be a multiple of the first member (`std::complex`):

```
struct dummy {
    std::complex<double> a;
    double b;
    std::int64_t b2;
    int c;
};

struct data {
    std::complex<double> a;
    double b;
    std::int64_t b2;
    int c;
    char padding[ ((offsetof(dummy, c) + sizeof(c)) / sizeof(std::complex<double>) + 1)* sizeof(std::complex<double>) - (offsetof(dummy, c) + sizeof(c)) ];
};
```

Note the formula is even worse now.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Are you planning on creating a serialization scheme?

Comment: @PepijnKramer, no, I want to see (in memory) an array of employee as an strided array of std::string (names). This is similar to the goal here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57424150/align-offset-specific-members-of-a-struct, but the problem is less offuscated here, and also I realize that in generalit was not a problem of alignment but simply of sizes.

Comment: So you have a code that requires the stride to be a multiple of `sizeof(std::string)`? Is it not possible to specify the stride in bytes?

Comment: Is this for debugging or to have some kind of fast access at runtime? Because at runtime the prefetcher will detect that you are repeatedly accessing the same member (and that will have a predictable stride anyway). If it is for the debugger, you might want to create view for your datatype and use that instead (and keep your runtime code unaffected)

Comment: Using an anonymous bitfield seems to preserve aggregateness nicely: `char : 8*num_padding_bytes;`. But out of the big three, MSVC rejects bitfields larger than the underlying type size.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I get this question often; no, it is for a whole framework that assumes that strides are given in multiples of the element's size. The fact is that legacy C libraries, numeric and otherwise, fortran, etc, use *element-size* strides. It also simplifies the pointer arithmetic, I think. Here it is a more numeric example (also I realized that I should look into the offsets as well) https://cppinsights.io/s/971006bf

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, NVCC also warns about this: `warning #959-D: declared size for bit field is larger than the size of the bit field type; truncated to 8 bits`, clang might warn with `-Wbitfield-width`. Some flags combinations (not sure) in GCC can give `width of ‘employee::padding’ exceeds its type`.

Comment: @alfC Yeah, I mean only in MSVC it appears to be a hard error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, in case you are interested, this is the original example that happened to work on Linux amd64, but lately I realized it didn't work for Apple ARM: https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/test/member_array_cast.cpp?ref_type=heads#L89-94

Comment: Are you aware that the size of `std::string` depends on the standard library and compiler being used? It's not just "amd64 linux", it's "amd64 linux with libstdc++ in debug mode"

Comment: @Botje, I imagined, which makes my need for an automatic solution even stronger. Use the other example (`data`) for a type that is a bit less dependent on the environment.

Comment: @DanielLangr I think the function will not give the correct padding if there are gaps between the members.

Comment: @DanielLangr, here it is a counter-example in which the function you propose doesn't work: https://cppinsights.io/s/ac7a262f . It seems that using offset is inevitable.

Comment: For the most recent example, in which the `static_assert` was failing with _8 != 0_, the calculations seem all right if you use a ```union PaddedData {
    data d;
    char buf[padding<std::complex<double>, double, int, int64_t>()];
};``` and adjust the `padding` function to return a total size rather than the remainder ie buf is `48`.
A union might make aggregate arguments harder but it means that you can separate your struct with important data from the less important padding.

Comment: @alfC You're right, I haven't considered this case, my bad. I deleted my comment, since in was no longer relevant.

Comment: static constexpr std::size_t fixed_size = sizeof(short) + sizeof(std::size_t);
static constexpr std::size_t string_alignment = alignof(std::string);
static constexpr std::size_t padding_needed = (fixed_size % string_alignment) == 0 ? 
                                                  0 : 
                                                  string_alignment - (fixed_size % string_alignment);
char padding[padding_needed];

need something like that?

Comment: "I want to see (in memory) an array of employee as an strided array of std::string (names)." Doing so would invoke UB.

Comment:  `short salary;` and `std::size_t age;` tells you something about life, world, society, economy and all that stuff. Yes, that’s just how things are!

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek, I overlooked that! I changed the integer types randomly to make the case. But given that people will work forever with meager salaries, perhaps it was the right choice of types. Wrapping around salaries is not a problem, but overflowing age, *that* is a problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a standard-compliant, no ifs or buts, version.

```
template <template<std::size_t> class tmpl, std::size_t need_multiple_of>
struct adjust_padding
{
    template <std::size_t n>
    static constexpr std::size_t padding_size()
    {
        if constexpr (sizeof(tmpl<n>) % need_multiple_of == 0) return n;
        else return padding_size<n+1>();
    }

    using type = tmpl<padding_size<0>()>;
};
```

Use it like this:

```
template <std::size_t K>
struct need_strided
{
    double x;
    const char pad[K];
};

template <>
struct need_strided<0>
{
    double x;
};

using strided = adjust_padding<need_strided, 47>::type;
```

Now `strided` has a size that is a multiple of 47 (and of course is aligned correctly). On my computer it is 376.

You can make `employee` a template in this fashion:

```
template <std::size_t K>
struct employee { ...
```

or make it a member of a template (instead of `double x`):

```
template <std::size_t K>
struct employee_wrapper { 
   employee e;
```

and then use `employee_wrapper` as a vector element. But provide a specialization for 0 either way.

You can try using `std::array` instead of a C-style array and avoid providing a specialization for 0, but it may or may not get optimized out when the size is 0. `[[no_unique_address]]` (C++20) may help here.

Note, something like `adjust_padding<need_strided, 117>::type` may overflow the default constexpr depth of your compiler.

Comment: The idea is almost foolproof. The recursion might indicate bigger problems like too much end-padding needed. A couple of modifications though: 1. make `pad_` non-const, otherwise default assignment doesn't work. 2. benefit from non-standard zero-sized arrays and `[[no_unique_address]]`, not sure if it is a suggestion or mandatory. 3. I replaced `char[K]` by `std::array<char, K>`, 4. I had to initialize `pad_` otherwise, default operator== might not produce the correct result, and I would be forced to implement operator==. Other niceties and a concrete use here: https://godbolt.org/z/K3Y61eY5b

Comment: @alfC You are right, it should not be const.

Answer (score 4):

Given the context provided by the comments, the OP's primary goal is to create a struct where the size is a multiple of the size of `std::string` to facilitate treating an array of such structs as an array of `std::string` with a certain stride for legacy compatibility reasons.

The C++ standard does not define the layout of memory in such a way that you could safely [stride through an array of objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stride_of_an_array) as if it were an array of one of its members.
That is due to padding, alignment requirements, and potential undefined behavior when accessing out-of-bounds memory or creating pointers that do not point to the beginning of an object.

I tried this [JDoodle SizeAdjuster project](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/Qkt) as a simpler approach:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

// Original employee struct with `salary` as an int
struct employee {
    std::string name;
    int salary;  // Changed from short to int
    std::size_t age;
};


// SizeAdjuster to make the size of a struct a multiple of the size of a member
template <typename T, typename MemberT>
struct SizeAdjuster {
    T data;
    // Calculate padding needed to make the size of T a multiple of the size of MemberT.
    char padding[(-sizeof(T)) % sizeof(MemberT)];
};

// Adjusted employee struct with padding
using employee_adjusted = SizeAdjuster<employee, std::string>;

int main() {
    // Create an employee object with adjusted size, salary is now an int, so 50000 is valid.
    employee_adjusted emp_adj = {{"John Doe", 50000, 30}};

    // Access and display employee data
    std::cout << "Name: " << emp_adj.data.name << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Salary: " << emp_adj.data.salary << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Age: " << emp_adj.data.age << std::endl;

    // Display the size of the adjusted employee object
    std::cout << "Size of employee: " << sizeof(employee) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of std::string: " << sizeof(std::string) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of employee_adjusted: " << sizeof(employee_adjusted) << std::endl;

    // Check if the size of employee_adjusted is a multiple of the size of std::string
    std::cout << "Is size of employee_adjusted a multiple of the size of std::string? "
              << (sizeof(employee_adjusted) % sizeof(std::string) == 0 ? "Yes" : "No") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

That would take into account the issue with zero-sized arrays and attempts to avoid undefined behavior by ensuring that we always have a well-defined `padding` array. However, even with this adjustment, the act of striding through an array of `employee_adjusted` objects as if it were an array of `std::string` objects may still invoke undefined behavior.

The goal of the `SizeAdjuster` is to make sure the size of the `employee_adjusted` struct is a multiple of the size of `std::string`. In the given output:

```
Size of employee: 48
Size of std::string: 32
Size of employee_adjusted: 64
Is size of employee_adjusted a multiple of the size of std::string? Yes
```

That indicates that the original `employee` struct has a size of `48` bytes, and the size of `std::string` is `32` bytes.
The `SizeAdjuster` has done its job by adding enough padding to the `employee` struct to make the total size a multiple of the size of `std::string`, which is `64` bytes in this case. Since `64` is a multiple of `32`, the condition `sizeof(employee_adjusted) % sizeof(std::string) == 0` is true, which is what we wanted to achieve.

The purpose of making the size of `employee_adjusted` a multiple of the size of `std::string` is to align the memory layout in such a way that when you have an array of `employee_adjusted` objects, you could theoretically access the `name` member directly at consistent strides. In the OP's context, this is intended for compatibility with legacy systems or frameworks that expect such memory alignment.

However, it is important to reiterate that while we can make sure the size of the struct is a multiple of the size of `std::string`, accessing the memory as if it were an array of `std::string` is not guaranteed to be safe or standard-compliant. The standard does not support treating an array of `employee_adjusted` as an array of `std::string` due to potential strict aliasing violations and alignment issues.

In practice, the `SizeAdjuster` project demonstrates how to calculate and apply padding to achieve a size requirement, but it does not endorse or implement unsafe memory access patterns.
The proper way to access the `name` member of each `employee_adjusted` in an array would still be through the `employee` object itself, not by treating the memory as an array of `std::string`.

The output illustrates that the size adjustment has been achieved, but it does not illustrate safe or standard-compliant striding access, which is beyond the capabilities of size adjustment alone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   struct employee {
       std::string name;
       union {  
          struct {
              short salary;
              std::size_t age;
          };
          std::string dummy;
       };
   };
```

This should be 2 * sizeof(std::string) on any platforms or compilers. But just in case, someone should tell me why this is not the case and on which platform will this fail! Thanks!

This can easily be generalized to collection of data field of any size. As long as there is enough copies of std::string to cover the size of the total in the original struct to enforce the size of N * sizeof(std::string) in the altered struct where N is an integer.

Comment: Interesting idea. However, 2 points: First, you cannot have an anonymous union because you need to define the destructor; otherwise, you get a compiler error. Second, this only works if the data within the anonymous struct has a size of less or equal the size of `std::string`. If it is larger, you'd have to add additional `dummy` elements (in their own struct). Example on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/zseezYYzf).

Comment: @Sedenion Tried it in Visual Studio, no compiler error there. I am aware of that the collected data size must be less than or equal to std::string for this to work. But this is the example given by the OP. You can always add more multiple of std::string dummy1, dummy2, dummy3 to expand the size. The bottom line is that the whole structure can be a multiple of sizeof(std::string).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to make `employee` a template or to list its members twice. TL;DR: You can get down to succint code such as:

```
#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end.
struct employee_base {
    std::complex<double> a;
};

using employee = PaddingHelper<employee_base>;
```

Explanation follows.

---

The core idea is that (since C++17) you can simply derive from the type that contains the actual payload, and keep the aggregate initialization syntax ([live on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/4ErfdaKhP)):

```
#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end of 'dummy'.
struct dummy {
    std::complex<double> a;
    double b;
    std::int64_t b2;
    bool c;
};

struct employee : dummy {
    char padding[
        (sizeof(dummy)/sizeof(decltype(dummy::a))+1)*sizeof(dummy::a) 
        - sizeof(dummy)]
        = {0};
};

static_assert(sizeof(employee) % sizeof(decltype(dummy::a)) == 0);

int main(){
    employee e{{41, 42, 43, false}};
}
```

The `#pragma pack` is of course non-standard, but gcc, clang and MSVC support it. We need it to ensure that we have control of the padding ourselves.

Note that if the base class has only a single member (or its size is a multiple of the first member), this adds additional padding. To fix this, we can exploit the [empty base class optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo) (live on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/njd3Yo8Ec)):

```
#pragma pack(1)
template <std::size_t size>
struct padding{
    char pad[size] = {};
};

template <>
struct padding<0>{};

template <class BaseClass, class FirstMember>
constexpr auto GetPaddingSize()
{
    constexpr auto Size = 
        (sizeof(BaseClass) % sizeof(FirstMember) == 0
            ? 0 
            : (sizeof(BaseClass)/sizeof(FirstMember)+1)*sizeof(FirstMember) 
                - sizeof(BaseClass));
    return Size;
}

#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end of 'dummy'.
struct dummy {
    std::complex<double> a;
};

struct employee : dummy, padding<GetPaddingSize<dummy, decltype(dummy::a)>()> {
};

static_assert(sizeof(employee) % sizeof(decltype(dummy::a)) == 0);
static_assert(sizeof(employee) == sizeof(decltype(dummy::a)));

int main(){
    [[maybe_unused]] employee e{{41}};
}
```

---

Since you are dealing with aggregate types, you could use [`boost::pfr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_pfr.html) to get rid of the explicit specification of the first member via `boost::pfr::tuple_element_t<0, BaseClass>` ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/GPM4cPsbd)):

```
#include <boost/pfr.hpp>

#pragma pack(1)
template <std::size_t size>
struct padding{
    char pad[size] = {};
};

template <>
struct padding<0>{};

template <class BaseClass>
constexpr auto GetPaddingSize()
{
    using FirstMember = boost::pfr::tuple_element_t<0, BaseClass>;
    constexpr auto Size = 
        (sizeof(BaseClass) % sizeof(FirstMember) == 0
            ? 0 
            : (sizeof(BaseClass)/sizeof(FirstMember)+1)*sizeof(FirstMember) 
                - sizeof(BaseClass));
    return Size;
}

//--------------------

#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end.
struct employee_base {
    std::complex<double> a;
};

struct employee : employee_base, padding<GetPaddingSize<employee_base>()> {
};

static_assert(sizeof(employee) % sizeof(decltype(employee::a)) == 0);
static_assert(sizeof(employee) == sizeof(decltype(employee::a)));

//---------------------

#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end.
struct foo_base {
    std::size_t i;
    bool b;
};

struct foo : foo_base, padding<GetPaddingSize<foo_base>()> {
};

static_assert(sizeof(foo) % sizeof(decltype(foo::i)) == 0);

//---------------------

int main(){
    [[maybe_unused]] employee e{{41}};
    [[maybe_unused]] foo f{{41, false}};
}
```

---

And then you could introduce

```
template <class BaseClass>
struct PaddingHelper : BaseClass, padding<GetPaddingSize<BaseClass>()> {};
```

allowing to write e.g.

```
#pragma pack(1) // Prevent padding at the end.
struct employee_base {
    std::complex<double> a;
};

using employee = PaddingHelper<employee_base>;
```

See on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/73vv63xK3). Of course, you can do the analogous thing without `boost::pfr`, you just have to add a second template argument to `PaddingHelper` that receives the first member type.
I don't think it can become more succinct than this.

Comment: A different idea would be to use a flexible array as last member, and overload `operator new`. In other words, to effectively allocate more memory than the size of the class. I.e. to implement the padding requirement during runtime rather than compile time. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76534273/3740047) post ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/s35z4vWPT)). However, note that `sizeof` will of course not know about the additional memory. And it will work only for objects allocated on the heap. So I wouldn't recommend it. Also see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html

Comment: Interesting, lot to unpack :)  here. First question is, do I need double curly brackets now, right? (that is the main reason I discarded the inheritance option, but if that it is what it takes, ok)

Comment: From my understanding, double braces are not really required for the first version I have shown. See e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70673480/3740047) post. However, [clang prints a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/d74zhh959), hence I used double braces. I tend to think that this is a bug in clang. For the final version, also [gcc prints a warning](https://godbolt.org/z/43KaK891T), although a different one. Even with double braces. I think this is just a "be aware, you might have a bug" warning, and could be ignored.