# Using lambda function in constexpr constructor with std::tie

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, constexpr, stdtuple

I'm trying to use a constexpr constructor in C++17 with a lambda that uses `std::tie` to initialize fields in a class from a tuple.
The code is similar to this:

```
#include <tuple>

enum class Format {
    UINT8,
    UINT16
};

struct FormatInfo {
    const char* name = nullptr;
    int maxVal = 0;

    constexpr explicit FormatInfo(Format fmt) {
        auto set = [this](const auto&... args) constexpr {
            std::tie(name, maxVal) = std::make_tuple(args...);
        };

        switch(fmt) {
        case Format::UINT8:  set("uint8", 255); break;
        case Format::UINT16: set("uint16", 65535); break;
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    FormatInfo info(Format::UINT8); // ok
    constexpr FormatInfo info2(Format::UINT8); // fails
}
```

Calling the constructor as constexpr fails, with an error that there is a call to a non-constexpr function inside `set`. Even though both `std::tie` and `std::make_tuple` should be constexpr.

Making the lambda itself constexpr (`constexpr auto set = ...`) also fails with an error that `this` is not a constant expression.

Is there any way to make this work in C++17?

Comment: Unrelated: The program works with c++20 though. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9noPPbbs4)

Comment: As always, c++'s initialization rules are overly complicated.

Comment: Maybe since c++20 allows parentheses aggregate initialization. But then even after changing `()` to `{}` doesn't make it work in c++17. [Why does Clang 12 refuse to initialize aggregates in the C++20 way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68006844/why-does-clang-12-refuse-to-initialize-aggregates-in-the-c20-way)

Comment: The assignment operator of `tuple` in C++17 is not `constexpr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::tie` returns a tuple of reference types. [`std::tuple<...>::operator=`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator%3D) is *not* marked `constexpr` in C++17.

You can emulate what `operator=` does with other (`constexpr`) functions:

```cpp
auto set = [this](const auto&... args) {
    std::apply([&](auto&... tied) {
        (void(tied = args), ...);
    }, std::tie(name, maxVal));
    // std::tie(name, maxVal) = std::make_tuple(args...);
};
```

Or you can ditch the tuples:

```cpp
auto set = [this](const auto& name, const auto& maxVal) {
    this->name = name;
    this->maxVal = maxVal;
};
```